# sending variables from one service to another in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, service

I have 2 services and I want to send a variable to one and get the return. how do I do this?

here is my code

```
var services = angular.module('service', []);

services.factory('startApp',['$http','kickTheTires',
  function($http,kickTheTires){
    kickTheTires('this is my var');
}]);
services.factory('kickTheTires',[function(val){
    console.log(val)
}]);
```

thank you in advance!

Comment: can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
services.factory('startApp',['$http', function($http){
    return {
        getMyVariable : function() {
            return $http.get('myservice/abc');
        }
    };
}]);

services.factory('kickTheTires',['$http', function($http){
    return {
        getTheTires : function(myvar) {
            return $http.get('myservice/xyz?' + myvar );
        }
    }
}]);

startApp.getMyVariable().then(function(result) {
    return kickTheTires.getTheTires(result);
})
.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Services can communicate in this same way as controller service. 
Please see demo here

http://jsbin.com/kudoli/1/edit?console,output

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('fCtrl', function($scope,queryService){

  queryService.setquery("my day");
  queryService.getData();

});
app.factory('queryService', function(dataService){

  function setquery(q){

    dataService.query.q = q;

  }

  function getData(){

    dataService.getData().then(function(){
      console.log("--------------");
      console.log("service a");
      console.log(dataService.data.info);

    });

  }

  return  {

    setquery : setquery,
    getData:getData

  };


});
app.factory('dataService', function($http, $q, filterFilter) {

  var API = "https://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json";
  var query = {
    q: "",
    page: 0

  };
var data ={
  tracks: [],  info : {}
};

  var getData = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    console.log("--------------");
    console.log("service b");
    console.log("Call api");
    console.log(query);

    $http({
      method: 'get',
      url: API,
      params: query
    }).then(onSucess, onError);


    function onSucess(response) {

      angular.copy(response.data.tracks, data.tracks);
      angular.copy(response.data.info, data.info);
      deferred.resolve();
    }

    function onError() {

      alert("Can't get data");
      deferred.reject();

    }

    return deferred.promise;
  };

  return {

    data: data,
    query: query,
    getData:getData

  };

});
```